# How to change the text of a jsTree node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I believe that the rename_node method is the right approach.

The snippet displays a small tree and a couple of form fields that should allow editing of the node text, once one is selected.

The expected outcome is that the tree is updated with the new node text.  What is happening is nothing changes.

```js
var $tree;
$tree = $('#tree');
$tree.jstree({});

$tree.on('select_node.jstree', function(e) {
 var selectedNodes = $tree.jstree("get_selected", true);
 
 if  (selectedNodes.length == 1) {
  var currentNode = selectedNodes[0];
  $("#costcodeedit").val(currentNode.id);
  $("#nameedit").val(currentNode.text);
 }
 
});
    
$("#updateButton").on("click", function (e) {
 var $codeInp = $("#costcodeedit");
 var $nameInp = $("#nameedit");

 var currentNode = $tree.jstree("get_selected", true)[0];
 //console.log(currentNode);

 $tree.jstree('rename_node', currentNode, $nameInp.val());

 // also tried
 //$tree.jstree('rename_node', currentNode.id, $nameInp.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.4/jstree.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.4/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id='tree'>
<ul>
 <li id='costcode_100000'>100000 - Civil
 <ul>
  <li id='costcode_110000'>110000 - Indirect Costs
  <ul>
   <li id='costcode_111000'>111000 - Project Initialization
   <ul>
    <li id='costcode_111010'>111010 - Deliverables
    </li>
   </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>

<br>
<div>
 <div><label for="Code">Code</label>:<input id="costcodeedit" class="form-control" name="code" type="text" value="" disabled="disabled"></div>
 <div><label for="Name">Name</label>:<input id="nameedit" class="form-control" name="name" type="text" value=""></div>
 <div><button id="updateButton">Update</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Let me know if my answer works for you. I got it working on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently editing is disabled by default.

> $.jstree.defaults.core.check_callback
>
> Determines what happens when a user tries to modify the structure of
>   the tree If left as false all operations like create, rename, delete,
>   move or copy are prevented. You can set this to true to allow all
>   interactions or use a function to have better control.

```
$tree.jstree({
    'core': {
        'check_callback': true
    }
});
```